# How to create a byte array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, byte

Please have a look at the following header file:

```
#pragma once

class MissileLauncher
{
public:
    MissileLauncher(void);

private:
    byte abc[3];
};
```

This generated the error:

```
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
```

I tried to do it in this way:

```
byte *abc;
```

It also failed with the same error. However, I noticed I can call other built in type arrays in this way, for example, an int array. Why is this happening to byte array? How to solve this? I would like to assign the values in the cpp file. Any ideas?

Comment: There's no `*` in the code you present, so it can't possibly generate that error message. Please be accurate.

Comment: Also, where is `byte` coming from? It's not a standard type.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try

```
class MissileLauncher
{
public:
    MissileLauncher(void);

private:
    unsigned char abc[3];
};
```

or

```
using byte = unsigned char;

class MissileLauncher
{
public:
    MissileLauncher(void);

private:
    byte abc[3];
};
```

**Note: In older compilers (non-C++11) replace the `using` line with `typedef unsigned char byte;`

Comment: `char` need not to be one byte

Comment: `char` is guaranteed to be one byte; `sizeof(char) == 1`, always. But "byte" is not guaranteed to be 8 bits.

Comment: @Nicolás sizeof returns size in *chars*. The only guarantee the standard makes is that sizeof(char) is 1. The rest are undefined behavior. A byte is not guaranteed to be 1 char. POSIX 1-2001 seems to define CHAR_BIT macro to be 8. See: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Width-of-Type.html

Comment: @Dragas sizeof returns a byte count, a byte may be more than 8 bits https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof

Answer (score 14):

If you want exactly one byte, uint8_t defined in cstdint would be the most expressive.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/

Comment: Also, C++11 only it seems.

Comment: @MichaelPrice, no, it's available in previous C++s as well.  Use <stdint.h> instead of <cstdint>.  I'm using it today in some code as we speak.  :-)

Comment: @KellyBeard - <cstdint> is only available after C++11 was shipped (as a standard, portable method).  <cstdint> and <stdint.h> are not exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you can leverage the [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) type available in C++11. It can be used to represent a fixed sequence of `N` bits, which can be manipulated by conventional logic.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bitset>

class MissileLauncher {
 public:
  MissileLauncher() {}
  void show_bits() const {
    std::cout<<m_abc[2]<<", "<<m_abc[1]<<", "<<m_abc[0]<<std::endl;
  }

  bool toggle_a() {
    // toggles (i.e., flips) the value of `a` bit and returns the
    // resulting logical value
    m_abc[0].flip();
    return m_abc[0];
  }

  bool toggle_c() {
    // toggles (i.e., flips) the value of `c` bit and returns the
    // resulting logical value
    m_abc[2].flip();
    return m_abc[2];
  }

  bool matches(const std::bitset<3>& mask) {
    // tests whether all the bits specified in `mask` are turned on in
    // this instance's bitfield
    return ((m_abc & mask) == mask);
  }

 private:
  std::bitset<3> m_abc;
};

typedef std::bitset<3> Mask;
int main() {
  MissileLauncher ml;

  // notice that the bitset can be "built" from a string - this masks
  // can be made available as constants to test whether certain bits
  // or bit combinations are "on" or "off"
  Mask has_a("001");       // the zeroth bit
  Mask has_b("010");       // the first bit
  Mask has_c("100");       // the second bit
  Mask has_a_and_c("101"); // zeroth and second bits
  Mask has_all_on("111");  // all on!
  Mask has_all_off("000"); // all off!

  // I can even create masks using standard logic (in this case I use
  // the or "|" operator)
  Mask has_a_and_b = has_a | has_b;
  std::cout<<"This should be 011: "<<has_a_and_b<<std::endl;

  // print "true" and "false" instead of "1" and "0"
  std::cout<<std::boolalpha;

  std::cout<<"Bits, as created"<<std::endl;
  ml.show_bits();
  std::cout<<"is a turned on? "<<ml.matches(has_a)<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"I will toggle a"<<std::endl;
  ml.toggle_a();
  std::cout<<"Resulting bits:"<<std::endl;
  ml.show_bits();  
  std::cout<<"is a turned on now? "<<ml.matches(has_a)<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"are both a and c on? "<<ml.matches(has_a_and_c)<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Toggle c"<<std::endl;
  ml.toggle_c();
  std::cout<<"Resulting bits:"<<std::endl;
  ml.show_bits();    
  std::cout<<"are both a and c on now? "<<ml.matches(has_a_and_c)<<std::endl;  
  std::cout<<"but, are all bits on? "<<ml.matches(has_all_on)<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling using gcc 4.7.2

```
g++ example.cpp -std=c++11
```

I get:

```
This should be 011: 011
Bits, as created
false, false, false
is a turned on? false
I will toggle a
Resulting bits:
false, false, true
is a turned on now? true
are both a and c on? false
Toggle c
Resulting bits:
true, false, true
are both a and c on now? true
but, are all bits on? false
```

Comment: The question was a byte array, not a bit array

Answer (score 7):

Byte is not a standard type in C or C++.  Try char, which is usually and at least 8 bits long.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, using char array? Can it send values into USB ports just as bytes?\

Comment: When you use a char it's exactly one byte; so send 'char' to USB port in C / C++ you are actually sending  a byte.

Answer (score 2):

Byte is not a standard data type in C/C++ but it can still be used the way i suppose you want it. Here is how: Recall that a byte is an eight bit memory size which can represent any of the integers between -128 and 127, inclusive. (There are 256 integers in that range; eight bits can represent 256 -- two raised to the power eight -- different values.). Also recall that a char in C/C++ is one byte (eight bits). So, all you need to do to have a byte data type in C/C++ is to put this code at the top of your source file:
    #define byte char
So you can now declare
    byte abc[3];

Answer (score 1):

You could use Qt which, in case you don't know, is C++ with a bunch of additional libraries and classes and whatnot. Qt has a very convenient QByteArray class which I'm quite sure would suit your needs.

http://qt-project.org/

Comment: this is like javascript's "just use jquery" but for c++.