# Conveniently defining bitwise operators for enums for creating bit flags

Tags: c++, enums

In order to define an enum to be used as bit flags, one would define the enum itself, with appropriate values, and define bitwise operators for the enum type, as below.

```
enum ENUM_TYPE
{
    ET_VAL1    = 1L << 0,
    ET_VAL2    = 1L << 1
}

inline ENUM_TYPE operator& (ENUM_TYPE _a, ENUM_TYPE _b) 
{return ENUM_TYPE(static_cast<int>(_a) & static_cast<int>(_b));}

/* similarly for |, ^, ~, |=, &=, ^= */
```

The problem is that the definition of the bitwise operators takes a lot of space, makes code difficult to read, and is annoying to write, specially if various enums are defined.

One could create a template, as below, in a header file, and simply include that whenever necessary. This introduces the risk of using the bitwise operators on types for which one did not explicitly define them, however.

```
template<typename ENUM_T>
inline ENUM_T operator& (ENUM_T _a, ENUM_T _b) 
{return ENUM_T(static_cast<int>(_a) & static_cast<int>(_b));}
```

One could also create macros, as below. This seems error prone though?

```
#define BITWISE_AND(TYPE) inline TYPE operator& (TYPE _a, TYPE _b)\
        {return TYPE(static_cast<int>(_a) & static_cast<int>(_b));}

#define BITWISE_ALL(TYPE) BITWISE_AND(TYPE) /* and others */
```

What is the "correct" way to do the above? Are various flag definitions a code smell? What is normally done in production code?

Comment: You could: 1) put the operators into a namespace, so you can `using namespace enum_operators;` only where you need them. 2) use `std::underlying_type` to detect the correct type instead of assuming `int`, 3)  use `std::enable_if` and `std::is_enum` to constrain the templates.

Comment: This is somewhat subjective... but I would use the macros, this is what macros are good at.  The template is problematic because it will match unwanted types, such as pointers.

Comment: [This](http://blog.bitwigglers.org/using-enum-classes-as-type-safe-bitmasks/) is a complete implementation along the lines melak47 suggested

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question but, have you considered using `std::bitset<N>`? I find it a convenient approach to defining and working with flags. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>


using Flag = std::bitset<3>;

const Flag FOO("001");
const Flag BAR("010");
const Flag BAZ("100");

int main() {

  Flag thing("011");

  if((thing & FOO) == FOO) {
    std::cout << "thing has foo\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "thing does not have foo\n";
  }

  if((thing & BAR) == BAR) {
    std::cout << "thing has bar\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "thing does not have bar\n";
  }


  if((thing & BAZ) == BAZ) {
    std::cout << "thing has baz\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "thing does not have baz\n";
  }


}
```

Sample output:

```
$ g++ example.cpp -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra
$ ./a.out
thing has foo
thing has bar
thing does not have baz
```

For [more information on `std::bitset<N>` in cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset), where it is described as:

> The class template bitset represents a fixed-size sequence of N bits.
>   Bitsets can be manipulated by standard logic operators and converted
>   to and from strings and integers.

Comment: I had looked at std::bitset<N>, but there are a few things I don't like about the syntax. For instance, if you define the consts as positions, then manipulation of individual bits is great, but multiple flag manipulation is not possible. Something like `cont = POS1 | POS2`, or `if (cont & (POS1 | POS2))`. If the consts are defined as bitsets, as in your example, then you forgo the use of operator[], test, set, reset, flip, etc.

Comment: As well, individual bit manipulation is rather verbose `if ((thing & FOO) == FOO)` or `if ((thing & (FOO | BAR)).any())` or something like that. I've only recently looked at std::bitset<N>, and never used it, so my apologies if I overlooked something.

Comment: You can do all bit manipulations you mention. For example `Flag f = FOO | BAR` is a valid expression and it means what you expect it to mean. You **can** access individual bits via the `[]` operator; you can define a function to test/set flags (along the lines of `any(const Flag f, const Flag & mask)`; you can test/set/flip/negate anything you want (if you want to modify `FOO` and `BAR`, simply don't declare them `const`, though that would be weird).

Comment: I don't think I explained myself correctly. When designing an interface, one defines public const "flags" to be used by the user as arguments. With std::bitset, these can either be `const size_t VAL0_p = 0` or `const Flag VAL0_f("001")`. In the former case, something like `Flag f = VAL0_p | VAL1_p` does not work; rather, it doens't mean what it looks like. If you have `VAL0_p = 0;` and `VAL1_p = 1;`, you'd get "001", not the expected "011".

Comment: In the ladder case - when you define `const Flag VAL0_f("001")` - you cannot do, for instance, `Flag f; f.test(VAL0_f)`. It's only a nuance of course, but it forces you to either keep matching flag-position pairs, or define test/set/flip/etc. functions to take Flags as arguments.

Comment: I certainly cannot understand you. And I still don't. Have you read the `std::bitset<N>` docs? Possibly this other answer I gave can show you an example of their use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489407/how-to-create-a-byte-array-in-c/16489617#16489617

Comment: Yes I've read the documentation. I actually tried all the sited examples to ensure I was correct. In any case, like I said, merely a nuance. I've up-voted, but didn't accept it because it isn't really a direct answer to the question. Thank for the effort, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of bools and place that within a struct , making the final struct 'typesafe', with methods to set and modify if you are working in C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to redefine the operators anyway, why not use meaningful ones? The bitwise **or** operator makes no sense when you really want to say "`ET_VAL1` **and** `ET_VAL2`". Similarly, testing for a flag to be set should happen with a comparison operator, IMO. `&` is the logical operation that needs to be done, but "`flags` **and** `ET_VAL1`" doesn't look like a test at all.

See my answer to this other question for my way of defining bit flag sets: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41516273/7328782