# Convert Stream response to byte[] using C++ REST SDK

Tags: c++, rest

I am using C++ REST SDK to get a response from the API, and I need to convert `Concurrency::streams::basic_istream` to `byte[]`.

```
pplx::task<void> GetResponse()
{
    http_client client(url);
    return client.request(methods::GET).then([](http_response response)
    {
        std::wostringstream ss;
        ss << L"Server returned returned status code " << response.status_code() << L'.' << std::endl;
        std::wcout << ss.str();

        auto bodyStream = response.body();
    });
}
```

`bodyStream` is of type `Concurrency::streams::basic_istream`.

The `content-type` of the response I getting is `application/octet-stream`.

How can I convert it to `byte[]`?

Comment: What do you mean by byte[] ?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489407/how-to-create-a-byte-array-in-c for more information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using the [`http_response::extract_vector`](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1http_1_1http__response.html#a2dc26d0a1f79f0f31fdd6ec78a939cf0) method to return the response body as a byte array?

```
pplx::task<std::vector<unsigned char>> GetResponse()
{
    http_client client(url);
    return client.request(methods::GET).then([](http_response response)
    {
        std::wostringstream ss;
        ss << L"Server returned returned status code " << response.status_code() << L'.' << std::endl;
        std::wcout << ss.str();

        return response.extract_vector();
    });
}
```

Or even simpler if you don't need the stdout logging:

```
pplx::task<std::vector<unsigned char>> GetResponse()
{
    http_client client(url);
    return client.request(methods::GET).get().extract_vector();
}
```

You can then call `data()` on the returned `vector` to get a pointer to the underlying unsigned char array (which is equivalent to a byte array).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Do you also happen to know, how we can get byte arrays from a ``` Concurrency::streams::ostream``` by any chance? I'm receiving a file on the server and I need to check a couple of first bytes to identify the file sent.

Comment: @Rika I've posted an answer to your seperate question about this.